# Eclipse is not opening when click on eclipse.exe

Tags: eclipse

When i am trying to open eclipse exe file by double clicking, eclipse window is not opened.
Previously it is working fine but today it is not opened?
It will help full if any one gave quick fix .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There could be numerous reasons for that. Try the following approach:

- Try to find the workspace that eclipse normally uses when it starts. Depending on the operating system you are using, a location like `c:\users\agarwal\workspace` is standard.
- Find there a file `.metadata\.log`. This is a text file that should include some information about starting up, and the stack trace, if Java failed.
- If you cannot find that, see if `javaw.exe` is on your path, so eclipse will find at least a JRE to start eclipse. If that is not definded, define the following variables:

  - `JAVA_HOME`: the path to the installation directory of your JDK
  - `PATH`: expand that by `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`

Answer (score 2):

Possibly a hangup an it idles in the taskmanager?

Have you looked in the process tab for the "eclipse.exe" and, if its there, tried to kill it?

There was maybe a javaupdate which is the reason for not starting eclipse?